# Should my helper methods use Static classes in C#

Tags: c#

I have a number of helper methods within helper classes. In my company I see that others use these helper methods as below:

```
var abc = new HelperClass()
var def = abc.doAction("ghi");
```

Is there a benefit to having these as non-static classes and having to create an instance each time around? Would it not be better to declare the helper class as static and do the following:

```
var def = HelperClass.doAction("ghi");
```

If I do the latter then do I need to declare both the helper class and the doAction method as static?

Here's an example of some code I use:

```
namespace Power.Storage.Helpers
{
    public class SimplerAES
    {
        private static byte[] key = { 123, 217, 19, 11, 24, 26, 85, 45, 114, 184, 27, 162, 37, 112, 222, 209, 241, 24, 175, 144, 173, 53, 196, 29, 24, 26, 17, 218, 131, 236, 53, 209 };
        private static byte[] vector = { 146, 64, 191, 111, 23, 3, 113, 119, 231, 121, 221, 112, 79, 32, 114, 156 };
        private ICryptoTransform encryptor, decryptor;
        private UTF8Encoding encoder;

        public SimplerAES()
        {
            RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
            encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
            decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
            encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        }

       ...

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return encryptStream.ToArray();
        }

        public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
        {
            MemoryStream decryptStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(decryptStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            return decryptStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be correct to say this should not be static as it has a constructor that instantiates other classes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should make them `static` to avoid wasting memory on class instances.

In general, [any method that does not depend on the state of an instance should be static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245046.aspx).

Helper classes that contain nothing but static methods should themselves be declared `static` to prevent you from accidentally adding non-static members and from instantiating the classes.

Comment: Thanks. I just added an example of a class (from the internet) that I use. I notice that the author of this class didn't make it static and that's what started me thinking. Maybe this should be the subject of another question but can you see any reason why the author didn't make it static?

Comment: That code is not great.  The `ICryptoTransform`s should be disposed, not reused.  Therefore, it shouldn't be stateful.  Also, **do not hard-code the key**!

Answer (score 1):

I normally use static methods for helper classes, but if your helpers have state and perhaps they fit in a class that needs instantiation, then you should have instance methods.

I guess it is **dependent** on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and Yes, preferably use static class with static functions.

What about this

```
namespace Power.Storage.Helpers
{
public class SimplerAES
{
private static byte[] key = { 123, 217, 19, 11, 24, 26, 85, 45, 114, 184, 27, 162, 37, 112, 222, 209, 241, 24, 175, 144, 173, 53, 196, 29, 24, 26, 17, 218, 131, 236, 53, 209 };
private static byte[] vector = { 146, 64, 191, 111, 23, 3, 113, 119, 231, 121, 221, 112, 79, 32, 114, 156 };
private static RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();

public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
MemoryStream encryptStream = new MemoryStream();
ICryptoTransform encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);

using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
return encryptStream.ToArray();
}

public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] buffer)
{
MemoryStream decryptStream = new MemoryStream();
ICryptoTransform decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);

using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(decryptStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
return decryptStream.ToArray();
}
}
}
```

Comment: I just added to the original question.